# Show a div on a different page with php

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I want my contact form to change to 'mail successful' when a mail has been send. So the div from the contactform has to be `display:none` and the div from 'mail successful' has to be `display:block` right?

Somehow I don't succeed in this.

Here is a print screen and how I want it:
[image: How I want that it gets chanced]

This is the php code I use (only the end cause that's the only needed part):

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

if ($success) {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mail_succeed {
            display: block;
        }
        #mail_failed {
            display: none;
        }
        #contat-area{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    header('Location: index.php#contact');
    exit();
} else {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mail_failed {
            display: block;
        }
        #mail_succeed {
            display: none;
        }
        #contact-area{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    header('Location: index.php#contact');
    exit();
}
?>
```

This is the html code I have now (its quit a bit of code, I also added the modal because maybe its important):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
         <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <span class="close">x</span>
                    <h4>Contact Form</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="contact-area">
                        <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
                            <div class="nametel">
                                <div class="name">
                                    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="tel">
                                    <label for="Tel">Tel:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="Tel" id="Tel">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email">

                            <label for="Message">Message:</label><br>
                            <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button" onclick="showDiv()">
                        </form>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mail_succeed" style="display: none">
                        <h3>Mail succesfull send, go back to </h3>
                        <span class="close"><a href="index.php#contact">contact page</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mail_failed" style="display: none">
                        <h3>Mail not send, go back to </h3>
                        <span class="close"><a href="index.php#contact">contact page</a></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I possibly send to much code but i'm not sure what to leave away since it can be important.

Comment: Easier method would be `jQuery/Ajax`.

Comment: You need to write the conditional css in html page...

Comment: I don't know how to make a mail engine with jquery

Comment: What css is needed? Cause I think most off the css is us for this form is purely for decoration and not funcionality (and btw its a php file)

Comment: @Minegolfer : your form -> send data through jQuery/Ajax to php -> PHP answer : if true, then your jQuery will handle and you can modify css (say: green) of the div. If false, same, with ie: red

Comment: So i have to make css and jquery work together for this to work?

Comment: You cannot define style on contactengine.php and expect it to be on index.php. If you can't use `jQuery/Ajax`, send back a response something like `header('Location: index.php?resp=1');` in case of success & `header('Location: index.php?resp=2');` in case of failure. Then on `index.php` you can add styles depending on the response.

Comment: So `if ($success) {` handle a jquery/ajax code that makes `#mail_success{display:block}` and  `else{` handle a jquery/ajax code that makes `#mail_failed{display:block};` shortly explained?

Comment: @Minegolfer : just create 2 `css styles` 1 for success, 1 for fail. Then let jQuery handle it, it will apply the success'style upon response=true and the fail.style upon response=false

Comment: mhmh I am pretty new to php but how to use resp=1 and resp=2? Do I have to give it a value first like `$resp1="style"` and the same with `$resp2` ?    => But I think I will try with jquery since everyone says its easier :)

Comment: Does the page gets reloaded when you send the email?

Comment: @OldPadawan Like 2 different css files for success and fail? or just 2 different classes?

Comment: @Momenator yes it does sadly :(

Comment: 2 classes are enough :)

Comment: @OldPadawan Since you are online now, how to tell jquery he has to do something when php is finished? Then I don't have to search and then i can try it myself (i'll probably learn more from it then ;) )  I know how to give elements classes with jquery so that won't be a problem i'll just give it a `AddClass('show')` or `AddClass('hide')`

Comment: @Minegolfer : will show you a hint in a couple of minutes

Comment: @Minegolfer : [this](https://pastebin.com/Q4VGpjf7) is something you can play around with, not to be the best code, just to show what you can do : type 1 for green, or 2 for red, if not, regular = black

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm at my work so for now i'm gonna do it with the php answer I got, When I'm at home I'm gonna take the time to try to fully understand it :)  Thank for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `jQuery/Ajax` then you can do the following :

In `contactengine.php`, change your header redirects to:

`header('Location: index.php?resp=1#contact');`

and

`header('Location: index.php?resp=0#contact');`

respectively for success and failure.

Then on `index.php` add this little php code in your head section (or wherever you define styles):

```
if(isset($_GET['resp']) && $_GET['resp']==1){
     echo '
       <script type="text/javascript">$("#ButtonThatOpensModal").click();</script>
       <style type="text/css">
        #mail_succeed {
            display: block;
        }
        #mail_failed {
            display: none;
        }
        #contat-area{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>';
}
elseif(isset($_GET['resp']) && $_GET['resp']==0){
     echo '<style type="text/css">
        #mail_failed {
            display: block;
        }
        #mail_succeed {
            display: none;
        }
        #contact-area{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty nice, but everyone suggests jquery/ajax so is that better to use for some reason?

Comment: @Minegolfer Ofcourse its better, cleaner, short & precise, all of the above can be done in 2 lines of code 
`success: function(html) { $('#contact-area').hide(); },
error: function(html) { $('#contact-area').show(); }`

Also you don't need to refresh your page with ajax.

Comment: This almost worked like I wanted, the only problem that when its done, it goes into the contact page but not in the modal. Since the contact page does't have the modal page auto opened but you have to click a link for it and the page gets refreshed :/

Comment: Can you say in the link something like `index.php/?resp=0/modal#contact` or something? or i need to make a new question for that? :)

Comment: > Also i will try to do it in ajax then, if the code is better that way :P

Comment: @Minegolfer I edited my answer, you can use jquery to click on the button/element that triggers contact modal open using its id or class. But - ajax is always better:)

Comment: Here is an easy example of php form post using ajax : http://jsfiddle.net/barzik/QZ3ff/

Comment: That's without php? And does every webhost that supports php also support ajax?

Comment: Ah yes, but obviously you will have to add the CDN for jquery on your pages/sites, meaning adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">` in the <head> tag of your pages. Or you can dowload the cdn as local js file and upload on your own server.

Comment: Btw, it didn't open the modal by itself, I did add the new code.

Comment: On which element/button do you have to click to open the modal normally? Does it have an id? Have you included the CDN on your page? Are you calling the code to click on that element after the element is loaded on your page?

Comment: button: `<button id="myBtn">Contact form</button>` so yes it has an id and I chanced that piece of code, but no its not after the element is created, but doesn't it need to be in the header?

Comment: Nopes, you can add it as the last lines of your code as well. Only the CDN link has to be in header, even that's not mandatory, but is a good practice.
How will it click on the button until the button with the given id is loaded on the page? :)

Comment: I think I understand it now thanks! I added `<?php
if (isset($_GET['resp'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#myBtn").click();</script>';
}
?>` above my `</body>` and it works now ty :D

Comment: Is there some way to hide the `?resp=0#contact` from a url (like `www.website.com/index.php?resp=0#contact`) after it loaded the page? cause that looks kinda ugly, or is that hard to do?

Comment: Yes there is a way, its called Ajax :)
Otherwise there are a few things you can do, but none of them is a good practice to achieve what you want and makes things complex for no good reason, like:
-modifying .htaccess (best not do it),
-using sessions instead of GET variables,
-having the form posted on the same page etc.

If you really can't bear the ugliness of URL, you can use the last option, least complex for you I guess.

Comment: Having the form posted on the same page? Like not on a modal? Cause I have everything on 1 page (with page jumps etc)

Comment: Means whatever code you have on `contactengine.php`, put it on the top of `index.php` itself, then change the form action to `action=""` or `action="index.php"`, so that you don't have to redirect back from `contactengine.php` & hence not making your url ugly.

Comment: I think I will do that then (but then with an include to make my code look cleaner ;) ) thanks, i'll try it now :)

Comment: It doesn't work cause its gonna activate instantly when I am going to the site, it gives errors cause it tries to send a mail while it doesn't know the name,tel,mail and message.. also I don't want an empty mail every time the site will be visited

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it so it only activates when I open the modal :P thanks for everything